# match single <p> with preg_match

Tags: php

i have a snippet of string with only starting paragraph tags and so

strip_tags does not seem to work in this case when `</p>` is missing.

```
$sSnippet = "<p>foo";
preg_replace('<p>', '', $sSnippet) // removes only the "p" in <p> to "<>foo"
```

How can I achieve to remove the `"<p>"` in `"<p>foo"`?
I just want the "foo" string.

Comment: `echo strip_tags('<p>test');` responds with `test` for me.

Comment: what's the difference of the first two functions?

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot the opening and closing delimiter: `/`

```
$sSnippet = "<p>foo";
echo preg_replace('/<p>/', '', $sSnippet);
```

Outputs `foo`

[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/903685)

However, [`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) seems to work fine:

```
$sSnippet = "<p>foo";
echo strip_tags($sSnippet);
```

Outputs `foo` as well.

[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/903686)

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex instead:

```
$new = preg_replace("/<[^>]*>/", "", $sSnippet);
```